# How to increment ios badge notifiation count when app is not running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, badge

We are already done with the initial setup for implementing Push notifications and are able to send/receive notifications successfully.

Now, we have been looking for the possible solutions to handle badge count increment from ios app (especially when app is not in foreground) -

**1. Delegate the badge count calculation to server side.**
- If we think of offloading the task of badge calculation to app server, then question arises is that, how server side will get to know about the count of viewed notifications so that badge can be decremented accordingly.

**2. Use UIBackgroundModes and call 'didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler' method.** 
- Apple says, this method will get called when my app is either in foreground or background state. With this we should be able to track the count/notification info even when the app is in background & thus it probably enables us to do the necessary calculation in iOS app itself. 
However, we have noticed that this method doesn't invoke when app is in background. Does it work only for iOS Silent notifications.

Any guidance/help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to ask a question?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is done by most apps (WhatsApp, Mail). It means you have to send a lot of 'notification read' messages to the server.

As for option 2, it works only for silent notifications (as you already noted) and in my experience, it is not entirely reliable. There even seems to be a [rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537929/are-there-rate-limits-on-silent-push-notifications-in-ios-7) on these.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. However, I am just wondering whether we are missing on any point. Are you aware of any other possible ways. Thanks.

Comment: I received push notification in all state i.e. when app is in forground, background, close(terminated)..!
but my problem is that how to increment badge count when app is in background state and close (terminate) state???? 
Please tell me in details how i do it....?
my app badge count is only increase when app is in forground state.....?

if possible please tell me in brief.......!

Comment: @Kiranjadhav you can specify the badge count in the notification message itself; the operating system will then automatically update the badge count for you. It's too long/complicated to explain in a comment.

Comment: @Glorfindel,,,,

Thanks for ans.....!

if possible can u tell me exact what should i do for that?

Comment: No, that's not possible. It will depend on the framework/library you're using to send the push notifications, and should be covered by documentation/tutorials of that framework/library.