# 'content-available' notifications not always sent to app (didReceiveRemoteNotification)

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, background-fetch

I've added push notifications to my app, and the notifications are sent with `'content-available'`.

I'm seeing this wierd behviour that (usually) 2 of 5 notifications doesn't reach the app's `application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` function ***BUT ONLY WHILE NOT DEBUGGING***.

Yes, that right. There's a difference if I'm having the debugger attached or not.

In this scenario I always receive 5 out of 5 notifications in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

1. Run app from Xcode
2. Minimize it
3. Send 5 notifications
4. See 5 "system-notifications"
5. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called 5 times.

In this scenario I usually receive 3 out of 5 notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` (sometimes 4).

1. Run app from Xcode
2. Unplug USB
3. Minimize it
4. Send 5 notifications
5. See 5 "system-notifications"
6. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called 3-4 times.

My `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is simple:

```
var received = 0

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    received += 1
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = received
    sleep(2) // do some "work", same behaviour with or without this line...
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

And then I just reset `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber` and `received` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

- Yes, I do send the notifications"fast". Basically I send them with a `curl` command, in a for-loop.
- If I send with `curl &` (i.e start in parallel), **I see the same behaviour**.
- If I send regularly (not parallel), **I see the same behaviour**.
- If I send with `curl ; sleep` (i.e. wait 1 second between each curl cal) **I get all of them**.
- The `sleep` that I added in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` for testing doesn't make any difference. *My thought was that if notifications with 'content-availabe' was received while processing another in the background, it would drop any not send any 'content-availabe' to the app during this period.*

Comment: Push notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered; as you have found they can be rate limited.  Apps often behave differently under the debugger, particularly with respect to background execution limitations that are removed while debugging.

Comment: I do know that they are not guaranteed to be delivered, however I find it suspect that they'd "randomly" drop with the same behaviour. And, in this case, I always stay under 2~ish seconds, when 30 seconds is the limit, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: And actually, "There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs" according to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: While there are no limits on the push notifications you can send, there are limits on the number that will be received when it comes to background execution; See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537929/are-there-rate-limits-on-silent-push-notifications-in-ios-7 and the article that that answer links to.  You have pretty much shown this to be the case yourself; it works when you introduce a delay in the sending of the notifications.  I suspect that if you observe the device log in the device window you may even find a message about the discarded pushes

Comment: @Paulw11 From the PDF: **"Silent pushes are rate limited"**. It is NOT silent pushes that we send, we have an 'alert', a 'badge, and a 'sound'.

Comment: `Content-available=1` == "silent push". The alert and sound are only shown if the app is terminated, otherwise the notification is delivered to your app delegate silently. I am not trying to be difficult here; you have proven the issue yourself; if you slow the rate of of delivery you get all messages.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult either, but that's just not true. Got to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html, read under "Configuring a Silent Notification", the requirements for a silent notification are: 1. The payload’s aps dictionary **must include the content-available key** with a value of 1, and 2. The payload’s **aps dictionary must not contain the alert, sound, or badge keys**. I.e a push that contains 'alert', etc. is **NOT** a Silent Notification. Can we agree on that?

Comment: If you read the paragraph before that it explains that if those conditions aren't met then the alert may be displayed to the user instead of being delivered to your app; however it is the content-available=1 that prompts the delivery to your app delegate and this is the functionality that can be rate limited. You should not need to process content-available messages at a high rate

Comment: I cannot exactly spot the paragraph you're referring to, but sure, it would make sense. But I still find it hard to grasp that it is in fact this limit that is the problem. I mean, they say "try not to send more than a few notifications per hour", but that doesn't play very well with *it's fine to send 5 notifications with payload in 5 seconds, but it's not ok to send 5 notifications in 1 second*. You see where I'm getting? These limits refer to some notifications in an hour, but my "testing" is the same, when I send 100 in 15 minutes.

Comment: No intention to barge-in, but any notification which contains 'content-available' key (irrespective of alert, badge etc.) becomes low priority Push (Provided its not a Voip Push) & will get throttled. We have seen this throttling logic w.r.t. various parameters like charging, low battery, foreground, multiple notifications etc. By 'Few notifications per hour', I don't think Apple means that it won't throttle if app is receiving silent notification every second.

Comment: @Ayush Feel free to join :) As much clarification as possible.